# Macro concept in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, postgresql, oracle

Do any database engines have the concept of a C-like macro? Here would be an example where I'd just like to make it more readable:

```
SELECT
  SUM(Profit) AS Total,
  (SELECT AVG(Profit) FROM This 
     WHERE Category=This.Category AND Product=This.Product
     AND     PARSE_DATE('%M %d%, Y', CONCAT(This.Month ' 1, ' This.Year))
     BETWEEN PARSE_DATE('%M %d%, Y', CONCAT(This.Month ' 1, ' This.Year))
     AND PARSE_DATE('%M %d%, Y', CONCAT(This.Month ' 1, ' This.Year))-INTERVAL 3 MONTH
FROM Tbl
```

I would rather have something that looks like:

```
#define dt PARSE_DATE('%M %d%, Y', CONCAT(This.Month ' 1, ' This.Year))

SELECT
  SUM(Profit) AS Total,
  (SELECT AVG(Profit) FROM This
     WHERE Category=This.Category AND Product=This.Product
     AND dt BETWEEN dt AND (dt-INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
FROM Tbl
```

Does something like that exist or commonly-used in the major DBMSs?

Comment: As macro - no. User-defined function...

Comment: @Akina how would the above be done with a function though?

Comment: Each SQL dialect supports `CREATE FUNCTION` DDL statement - investigate.

Comment: @Akina sure I know that and I use those, but I mean how would a concept such as the above be substituted with a function?

Comment: There is no macro concept in SQL. Moreover, there is no any SQL code preprocessing. The most similar seems to be stored objects or dynamic SQL.

Comment: If feels like you are looking for a CROSS APPLY.   Perhaps it would aid in the visualization if you supply a small data sample and desired results

Comment: For function this will look like general function call: `date_from_parts_udf(this.year, this.month) between ...`. Or you may calculate this expression, provide it an alias `dt` and use it as you described: `where dt between dt and ...` (though, this is constant false because upper boundary is less than lower).

Comment: As John says, `CROSS APPLY` is the general mechanism to avoid repeating segments of a query.

Comment: Oracle supports defining functions inside of a common table expression (`WITH` clause)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name could you please show an example? I think that might be what I'm looking for...

Comment: @David542 https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6

Comment: @JohnCappelletti note that `cross apply` is non-standard SQL, the equivalent in ANSI SQL would be a `cross join lateral`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name wow, now those are some docs. It's incredible how complex that oracle select statement is...

Comment: *I would rather have something like* ... I would rather have a table where dates weren't stored as strings, so they didn't have to be parsed all the time.. That way I could just say `dateCol between @xdate and @ydate` and my indexes would work.. ;) But I'll stop poking fun at the contrived example; I knew what you meant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Oracle 12, you can declare a function inside a sub-query factoring (`WITH`) clause:

```sql
WITH FUNCTION dt (month INT, year INT) RETURN DATE AS
BEGIN
  RETURN TO_DATE(year || '-' || month || '-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD');
END;
SELECT *
FROM   this
WHERE  dt(this.month, this.year)
         BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(dt(this.month, this.year), -3)
         AND     dt(this.month, this.year);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=eac61614059cebc9a950019e35d1ae83)*

---

From Oracle 21, you can write [SQL macros](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/nfcon/details-sql-macros-282451004.html):

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dt (month INT, year INT)
RETURN VARCHAR2 SQL_MACRO(SCALAR)
AS
BEGIN
  RETURN 'TO_DATE(year || ''-'' || month || ''-01'', ''YYYY-MM-DD'')';
END;
/
```

Then would use it as:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   this
WHERE  dt(this.month, this.year)
         BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(dt(this.month, this.year), -3)
         AND     dt(this.month, this.year);
```

And the query would get rewritten as:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   this
WHERE  TO_DATE(this.year || '-' || this.month || '-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
         BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(this.year || '-' || this.month || '-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), -3)
         AND     TO_DATE(this.year || '-' || this.month || '-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD');
```